# Finding Forward and Inverse Kinematics of Manipulator

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, forward-kinematics, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I need a help regarding finding forward Kinametics and Inverse kinametics of a manipulator, I shall be thankful if any body can help me in this regard.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296766/finding-forward-and-inverse-kinematics-of-manipulator/) by [Sheby 99](https://answers.ros.org/users/36340/sheby-99/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey

Basically, Kinematics explain the motion representation of the joint frame of the manipulator without considering the force and the torque that cause the joint’s motion. Thus, it depends on the robot that you want to find the kinematics, {how many degree-of-freedom / and what are the joints types (revolute/prismatic)}

You will not find a straight forward answer, you should first understand the idea and build your own kinematics.

I recommend you to check some kinematics videos in [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/user/asodemann3/videos) you will understand the concept behind it, then you will be able to construct the kinematics solutions based on your robot.

I also recommend you to check this book,

Spong, Mark W., Seth Hutchinson, and Mathukumalli Vidyasagar. Robot modeling and control. Vol. 3. New York: Wiley, 2006.

Hope this helps,

---

Originally posted by [Abdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30451/abdu/) with karma: 36 on 2018-07-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sheby 99](https://answers.ros.org/users/36340/sheby-99/) on 2018-07-09**:
Thank you so much i know how to find forward and inverse kinametics but i need help it doing in ROS

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See:

- [tf2](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2) (forward kinematics | C++/Python)
- [Orocos Kinematics and Dynamics Library (KDL)](http://wiki.ros.org/orocos_kdl) (forward/reverse kinematics | C++/Python)
- [trac_ik](http://wiki.ros.org/trac_ik) (reverse kinematics | C++/Python)

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) with karma: 697 on 2018-07-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sheby 99](https://answers.ros.org/users/36340/sheby-99/) on 2018-07-09**:
How can i find Kinametics of Youbot through this thanks for the reply

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-07-09**:
If you have a URDF and are running the `robot_state_publisher` it should be easy to calculate the forward kinematics using `tf`. KDL can be used for forward/inverse using a URD... might want to check out [pykdl_utils](http://wiki.ros.org/pykdl_utils) for an easy interface.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-07-09**:
If you are using MoveIt!, trac_ik, bio_ik, and KDL can be used through standard MoveIt! interfaces. Since it sounds like you are just looking at the youBot, you might want to check out this [youbot_manipulation](https://github.com/svenschneider/youbot-manipulation) package that...

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-07-09**:
contains an IK solution specifically for the youBot.

**Comment by [Sheby 99](https://answers.ros.org/users/36340/sheby-99/) on 2018-07-09**:
Thank u so much for the reply
actually i want to solve this lab
https://github.com/surgical-vision/compgx01_lab
I have made the tf listener now i am looking for finding Forward Kinametics and Inverse Kinametics so i need a help in this regard
Thanks in anticipation

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-07-10**:
If you have a URDF+join_state information+robot_state_publisher you can just query for the transform from the base of your robot to the end-effector of your robot using your listener to get the result of the forward kinematics problem.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-07-10**:
As you might be getting the sense, there are a lot of kinematics packages and tools out there capable of solving your FK and IK problems, but none of them work without a little bit of work/configuration on your part. We've pointed out quite a few solutions for you...

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2018-07-10**:
... my advice would be to investigate these solutions to and then ask new questions about specific packages as they arise. I think it is unlikely that someone will just solve your problem for you, and there is no one-size-fits-all answer to this question.

**Comment by [Sheby 99](https://answers.ros.org/users/36340/sheby-99/) on 2018-07-11**:
Cheers for the help!!
Much Appreciated